# Community standard and pros/cons? Destructive vs. Non-destructive iteration

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, iteration, mutation

There are two basic ways I have seen to iterate over a collection of items (eg. a `list`, `array`, etc.). **One** is by increasing or decreasing the index, which tends to be the default for many "built-ins" (eg. `for` loops in python). **The other** is to slice the collection and always evaluate the first item.

These two approaches could "*work*" (but may not be ideal), IIRC, in many common web languages including Ruby, Javascript, and Python. So while I am asking abstractly about the non-language-specific approach, as @DavidMaze points out, this question might not be applicable to every language, or there may be vast language-specific differences.

For example, using Python:

**ONE**

```
collection_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
x = 0
while x < len(collection_1):
  print(collection_1[x])
  x += 1
print("collection_1: {}".format(collection_1))
```

result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
collection_1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**THE OTHER**

```
collection_2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
while len(collection_2) > 0:
  print(collection_2[0])
  collection_2 = collection_2[1:]
print("collection_2: {}".format(collection_2))
```

result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
collection_2: []
```

Obviously ONE is necessary to preserve the data, and THE OTHER gives some advantage if storage is limited and the data are no longer needed after the iteration. Aside from those scenarios, I would think ONE is generally more useful (and less likely to introduce bugs). I'd also think ONE is *probably* always or almost always less expensive to achieve the same result, but I want to test the above assumptions. I'm interested in:

- What are some common use cases (if any) where "THE OTHER" is preferable to "ONE"? Why?
- Can it be said that ONE is *always* or *almost always* preferable to THE OTHER?
- Is there an accepted standard or convention around this sort of thing?
- Is one approach significantly more expensive?
- Are the answers to the above true generally, or language-specific?

Comment: Are you asking about Python specifically, or more abstractly?  (Because I code recreationally in a language where neither option you mention is right, and one is actively impossible.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Abstractly. I didn't even think about the idea that some languages might not support this sort of dichotomy.

Comment: If one approach "is more preferable" (or even allowed) or "more expensive" depends on the language and implementation of such a language. Even within a language that supports both, it may largely come down to a particular problem.

Comment: @user2864740 So I'd say that fits within the "use case" maybe? Eg. I'm programming X in Y language...

Comment: I'm just furthering the position that such a question is 'not answerable' without a specific context (ie. language and problem), and even within such a context it MAY still be 'largely an opinionated decision'.

Comment: @user2864740 I hope not... the SO kiss of death. Thanks! I was hoping when I wrote it there was a non-opinion-based answer out there, but to some degree I can't ever really know that until I ask.

Comment: THE OTHER in Python is… the worst thing ever, and should never be used :D Slicing lists makes a copy, so it manages to take quadratic time, burn the data, and be hard to read. Same applies to JavaScript. I don’t know about Ruby. You would only use something like that in a language where lists are linked lists and probably as part of recursion, like a Lisp or Haskell. (Proper destructive iteration for the purposes of GC would be setting items to `None`, iterating backwards and deleting in place, etc.)

Comment: So… where have you seen this second form? ’cause I’ve actually never seen it quite like that.

Comment: In a specific context / language / problem, there *might* very well be reasons to choose one over the other .. but such is only 'in the details'.

Comment: @Ry- I don't remember. I think somewhere on GitHub. I thought it was very odd when I first saw it, but that novelty is probably also why it got stuck in my head.

Comment: @Ry- Lisp generally 'operates like' the 2nd form, FSVO..

Comment: @user2864740: That’s what I said, right?

Comment: @Ry- Sorry if/as I missed it .. :(

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest a rubric:

## 1. Match the style of your existing code base.

In a large project it can be helpful if things are written in a consistent style.  For super-low-level things like list iteration it's not necessarily a big deal, but if most things are "one" way doing the same task "the other" way will confuse people who come later.

## 2. If your language has native list iteration (like a "map" function), use it.

Most newer languages have some way to take action on the list as a whole, or else have some standard way to iterate through lists.

```py
# Python
for x in collection_1:
    print(x)
```

```
// Javascript
collection_1.forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

```hs
-- Haskell
mapM_ putStrLn collection1
```

```golang
// Go
for _, x := range collection1 {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", x)
}
```

In C and languages closely derived from it, indexing arrays is idiomatic, so do that *if it's the usual convention in that language*.

```c
/* C */
void printList(int *l, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", l[i]);
    }
}
```

## 3. Understand what type "list" is.

Different languages have different default implementations of lists with different characteristics.  If a "list" is a singly-linked list (Lisp, Haskell) then iterating through it an element at a time and passing on "the rest of the list" is actually right.

```hs
-- Haskell
-- printAList is a function that takes a list parameter
-- and returns an IO action producing no value in particular.
printAList :: [Int] -> IO ()
-- To print an empty list, do nothing.
printAList [] = return ()
-- To print a non-empty list:
printAList (x:xs) = do
  -- Print the first element;
  putStrLn (show x)
  -- Then print the list of things starting at the second element.
  printAList xs
```

Since it's a singly linked list, though, fetching an element by index can take O(*n*) time and you definitely don't want to do that.

In some languages "a list" is a start position plus a length (arrays in C, slices in Go) and in that case the "create a list of the rest" isn't that expensive, though it tends to look a little odd.

```c
/* C programmers will look at you funny */
void printList2(int *l, int len) {
    for (; len > 0; l++, len--)
        printf("%d\n", l[0]); /* or *l */
    }
}
```

```golang
// Go: also strange, but not wildly inefficient
func printList(l []int) void {
        while (len(l) > 0) {
                fmt.Printf("%d\n", l[0])
                l = l[1:len(l)]
        }
}
```

But if "a list" is a block of items and changing it involves copying the entire list (Python, as @Ry- suggests in comments) then you definitely don't want that; but then looking items up by index is relatively cheap.

```py
# Python; this is common to update a list in place
for i in range(len(container_1)):
    container_1[i] += 1
```

## 4. Gently prefer non-destructive actions.

On modern hardware, expensive things are I/O, network calls, and bad algorithms.  Small efficiencies mostly don't matter.  Is there a practical difference between:

```py
# Python

def doubleListInPlace(l):
  for i in range(len(l)):
      l[i] *= 2
  return l

def doubleListAndCopy(l):
  return [2 * x for x in l]

def main():
  l = [1, 2, 3]
  ll = doubleList...(l)
  lll = doubleList...(ll)
  print("Doubled list: " + repr(ll))
  print("Quadrupled list: " + repr(lll))
```

The immutable ("...andCopy") form allocates an extra list, sure, but when you go to use the result later there are fewer surprises waiting, and you (usually) won't notice the extra allocation.  Using a more immutable style is also very helpful in testing (you can create a test fixture once and reuse it across tests) and for maintaining an undo stack (this is core to the "time-traveling debugger" in the Javascript Redux framework, for instance).

> Is one approach significantly more expensive?

If your "native" list type is a singly-linked list, then trying to iterate through it by index takes O(*n*^2) time (you must traverse all *n* elements to get to the last one, plus *n*-1 to get to the second-to-last one, plus...).  If your "native" list type is based on an array or vector, then working with sublists will take O(n^2) time (you must copy all *n*-1 items you haven't yet processed).  There's no specific universal cross-language answer to this.